# Python compare keys values from same dictionary not working

Tags: python, dictionary, comparison

I am learning python and I don’t get why this simple piece of code does not work.

```
list = {"Text":"Text"}

print(list)

if list.keys() == list.values():
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

This returns `False` when it should return `True`.

Comment: please change the `dict` name to something else, like `my_list`, or `my_dict`. If you just print `x.keys()` and `x.values()`, you will see, that one is a `dict_keys` object, and the other is `dict_values` object, so yes, they are not the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keys()` and `values()` don't return lists, they return iterator objects that yield the keys and values. If you want to compare the contents, convert them to lists, using the `list()` function.

You won't be able to do this in your snippet because you've redefined the name `list` to your dictionary. You should use a variable name that isn't the same as a built-in function.

```
my_dict = {"Text":"Text"}

print(my_dict)

if list(my_dict.keys()) == list(my_dict.values()):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Comment: But what if I want to print `True` if at least **one** of the pairs is identical (*i.e.* a dictionnary as such: `my_dict = {"Text":"Text", "Other Text":"That is not identical", "and other text":"and other text"}`)? Because with the current code, it only allows me to compare if the full dict has all identical keys...

Comment: `if any(key == value for key, value in my_dict.items())`

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The type of dict.keys() and dict.values() is different so must cast both to a list object to compare.

```
data = {"Text":"Text"}

a = data.keys() 
b = data.values()

print(a)
print(b)
print(a == b) # False

if list(a) == list(b):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Output:

```
dict_keys(['Text'])
dict_values(['Text'])
False
True
```